# Javascript phone number validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate a phone number in javascript.
The requirements are:

> they should be 10 digits, no comma, no
>   dashes, just the numbers, and not the
>   1+ in front

this is what I wrote so far

```
function validatePhone(field,alerttxt) {
    with (field) {
        if(value.length > 10) {
            alert(alerttext);
            return false;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if(parseInt(value[i]) == NaN) {
                alert(alerttxt);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
function validateForm(thisform) {
        if (validatePhone(phone,"Invalid phone number")==false) {
            phone.focus();
            return false;
        }

    }
}
  <form action="post.php" method="post" id="contactform" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)">
    <ol>
        <label for="phone">Your phone <span class="red"></span></label>
        <input id="phone" name="phone" class="text" />
      </li>
    </ol>
  </form>
```

but, obviously it doesn't work.
How can I write the `validatePhone()` function so that it works?

Comment: What an unfriendly system. Let people enter spaces and dashes, then ignore them. And what about international phone numbers?

Comment: This looks like a school assignment. For serious use, you *shouldn't* use regular expressions to [validate phone numbers properly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4338544/1269037).

Comment: @DanDascalescu Actually, at that time, it wasn't a school assign. Just a shitty job on RentACoder

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
if(phone.length != 10) { 
   alert("not 10 digits");
} else {
  alert("yep, its 10 digits");
}
```

This will validate and/or correct based on your requirements, removing all non-digits.

Comment: as I said "validate and/or correct" is why not just match. Its pretty poor user experience to force someone to enter a phone number sans spaces or dashes when they are so easy to remove.

Comment: @FedericoCulloca: there is no "correct" regexp for the general case of validating phone numbers properly. [See why here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4338544/1269037) Aaron's answer is the only correct one on this page.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - No one asked for the general case.

Answer (score 11):

Google's [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) is very helpful for validation and formatting of phone numbers all over the world. It is easier, less cryptic, and more robust than using a RegEx, and it comes in JavaScript, Ruby, Python, C#, PHP, and Objective-C flavors.

Comment: *This*. People just don't seem to understand that [regular expressions are naive solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links/21925491#21925491) when it comes to validating real-world data.

Answer (score 7):

You could use Regular Expressions:

```
function validatePhone(field, alerttext) {
    if (field.match(/^\d{10}/)) {
         return true;
    } 
    alert(alerttext);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You *shouldn't*, in fact, use regular expressions to [validate phone numbers properly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4338544/1269037).

Comment: His requirement says that he should check for a 10-digit-format without anything else. So this regular expression check should be ok. You are right: I dont like applications that force me into a specific phone number format. A check for minimum length, for numbers and some ()-+/ characters in any order might be ok, like in: `^[0-9 ()+/-]{5,}$`

Answer (score 1):

Code to except only numbers braces and dashes

```
function DoValidatePhone() {
    var frm = document.forms['editMemberForm'];                
    var stripped = frm.contact.value;
    var isGoodMatch = stripped.match(/^[0-9\s(-)]*$/);
    if (!isGoodMatch) {
        alert("The Emergency Contact number contains invalid characters." + stripped);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed function:

```
function validateForm(thisform) {
        if (validatePhone(thisform.phone,"Invalid phone number")==false) {
            thisform.phone.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to include with(thisform) at the beginning of the function, but actually I wrote it)

Comment: But you also have extra "}" symbol

Answer (score 0):

Add the pattern in which format you want directly in input tag.

```
<input id="phone" name="phone" pattern="\d{10}" class="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout joi: https://github.com/Salesflare/joi-phone-number

```
const myCustomJoi = Joi.extend(require('joi-phone-number'));

myCustomJoi.string().phoneNumber().validate('+32494567324');

// The phone number can be transformed to a custom format
// Note that this follows Joi's `convert` option
myCustomJoi.string().phoneNumber({ defaultCountry: 'BE', format: 'e164' }).validate('494322456'); // '+32494322456'
myCustomJoi.string().phoneNumber({ defaultCountry: 'BE', format: 'international' }).validate('494322456'); // '+32 494 32 24 56'
myCustomJoi.string().phoneNumber({ defaultCountry: 'BE', format: 'national' }).validate('494322456'); // '0494 32 24 56'
myCustomJoi.string().phoneNumber({ defaultCountry: 'BE', format: 'rfc3966' }).validate('494322456'); // 'tel:+32-494-32-24-56'
myCustomJoi.string().phoneNumber({ defaultCountry: 'US', strict: true }).validate('7777777777'); // validation error
myCustomJoi.string().phoneNumber({ defaultCountry: 'US'}).validate('7777777777'); // 7777777777
```