# Where in the code to validate a phone number, in JavaScript orRazor?

Tags: javascript, razor

This is my first webpage in which I prompt the user for a phone number to add to a Do Not Call List database. Everything is working so far but I need to add the following, which I can do following the advice [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386054/javascript-phone-number-validation)

- stripping the input from all characters except digits
- validating that the resulting string is 10 digits long

Then, when telling the user that the number was added to the list, I want to present it in the (999) 999-9999 format.

Where should I add all that code? Iside the `@{ }` block? In JavaScript? Razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check phone number

```
function IsNumber(s) {
    var i, currentCharacter;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        // Check that current character is number.
        currentCharacter = s.charAt(i);
        if (((currentCharacter < "0") || (currentCharacter > "9"))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // All characters are numbers.
    return true;
}

function TestInternationalPhone(strPhone) {
    var bracket = 3,
    openBracket,
    phoneNumberOnly,
    phoneNumberDelimiters = "()- ",
    validWorldPhoneChars = phoneNumberDelimiters + "+",
    minDigitsInIPhoneNumber = 10;

    strPhone = SOS.StringHelper.Trim(strPhone);
    if (strPhone.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (strPhone.indexOf("+") > 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (strPhone.indexOf("-") != -1) {
        bracket = bracket + 1;
    }
    if (strPhone.indexOf("(") != -1 && strPhone.indexOf("(") > bracket) {
        return false;
    }
    openBracket = strPhone.indexOf("(");
    if (strPhone.indexOf("(") != -1 && strPhone.charAt(openBracket + 2) != ")") {
        return false;
    }
    if (strPhone.indexOf("(") == -1 && strPhone.indexOf(")") != -1) {
        return false;
    }
    phoneNumberOnly = SOS.StringHelper.StripCharsInBag(strPhone, validWorldPhoneChars);
    return (IsNumber(phoneNumberOnly) && phoneNumberOnly.length >= minDigitsInIPhoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but where in the code should I put that? Inside the `@{ }` block? In a JavaScript file, and call it from inside the `@{ }` block?

Comment: If you put it in @{ }, you should put it inside tag <text> </text>. I put it in my JavaScript file.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. What's  <text> </text> ? I googled it and didn't find any explanation to it.

Comment: in razor view, when you put your code in @{ } it mean server code, no javascript. Tag <text> </text> just help you to put the javascript inside this server block code.

Comment: I was doing `<script> </script>`. Doesn't it work? Is it the same?

Comment: No, it not the same. this my working code: <script type="text/javascript">
 // javascript code
  @{
   // server code
    <text>
     // javascript code
    </text>
   // server code
  }
 });
 // javascript code
</script>

Comment: Oh, I see. I've been busy at work with other pressing issues. Will try this sometime next week. Thanks.