# Need phone validation for 10 digits, spaces and hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex

I looked around and saw lots of regex examples but not one I'm looking for. I need to verify 10 digits, allow spaces and dashes but not parenthesis or other characters.

Here is what I'm currently using:

```
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var error = "";
    var stripped = phone.value.replace(/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/, '');

    if (phone.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "Please enter a phone number";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
        var error = '6';
    } else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
        var error = "5";
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "The phone number contains illegal characters.";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else if (stripped.length < 10) {
        var error = "6";
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "The phone number is too short.";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else {
        phone.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is significantly easier to just put a little note under the text box saying "please enter numbers only - no spaces or symbols" and then check you have 10 digits.

Comment: Why validate like this? Phone numbers differ. Already, your 10-digit validation will fail my 11-digit mobile phone number.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2386081/712526 It removes extra characters instead of disallowing them. (Hey, I *like* using parens when I type a phone number!)

Comment: All good comments. It's for an project that has specific requirements.

Comment: A good case for the Prussian Stance. http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001527/ch03.html#vicunas-03-3

Comment: You should really be testing server-side. I run phone numbers through a regex that strips out all but numeric characters, then check that it is either 10 characters, or 11 preceded by a 1, if I'm only targeting the US and Canada. On the Javascript side, you could do the same thing. In this case I would also replace their field with only numeric, spaces, parentheses and hyphens, so that if they type things like letters, etc. they understand that is not going to be parsed.

Comment: why the down vote. it's a very legit question. if you don't like the objective then move on.

Comment: this is for an assignment, that is why the specific request.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'd do:

```
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var error = "";
    var stripped = phone.value.replace(/\D+/, ''); // strips all non digit characters

    if (stripped == "") {
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "Please enter a phone number";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
        error = '6';
    } else if (phone.value.match(/[^\d() .-]/)) {
        error = "5";
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "The phone number contains illegal characters.";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else if (stripped.length < 10) {
        error = "6";
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = "The phone number is too short.";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else {
        phone.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does? I'm new to regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace `\D` with empty space... So that you only have digits left.