# Validating Phone Numbers Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, phone-number

I'm working on a web form with several fields and a submit button. When the button is clicked, I have to verify that the required text boxes have been filled in and that the phone number is in the correct format. I can only accept 7 or 10 digit phone numbers, but characters such as (,), (-), etc are acceptable. If this box is empty or the phone number isn't in the correct format (not 7 or 10 numbers long, not a number) or has been left blank, I have to add a red border around the text box. This border is supposed to remain in place until the user corrects the error.

I can't get this to work properly. I have tried several different ways to go about doing this, but have gotten several different types of errors. One way seemed to work, but the red border only displayed for a second and then disappeared and the value in the textbox was reset.

Here is my code and a link to a jsfiddle I've created:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        return checkPhone();
    }
    function checkPhone() {
        var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
        var phoneNum = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/; 
            if(phone.value.match(phoneNum)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("phone").className = document.getElementById("phone").className + " error";
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit = "return validateForm()">
    Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone"><br>
</form>
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mkdsjc0p/

Comment: You're setting `phone` to the elements `value` property, then in the test, you're accessing the `value` property again, this time of the value you already got, which doesn't exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386054/javascript-phone-number-validation)

Comment: You already have a reference to the form control as *phone*, why use `document.getElementById`? And rather than *match*, you should be using [*test*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3).

Comment: This is not a dupe of the referenced question, because the criteria for "what is a phone number" are different.  The solutions presented in the referenced question would not meet the requirements here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As for your regexp I guess it should be

```
^\+{0,2}([\-\. ])?(\(?\d{0,3}\))?([\-\. ])?\(?\d{0,3}\)?([\-\. ])?\d{3}([\-\. ])?\d{4}
```

But in general the presumption is not correct because one might enter something like
++44 20 1234 56789 or +44 (0) 1234 567890
it is better to do something like this

```
var phone = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
var phoneNum = phone.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
if(phoneNum.length > 6 && phoneNum.length < 11) {  return true;  }
```

this will assure that entered value has 7 to 10 figures nevertheless what the formatting is. But you have to think about max length for number might be more than 10 as in the sample above.

Answer (score 8):

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  var a = /^(1\s|1|)?((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{4})$/.test(str);
  alert(a);
}
telephoneCheck("(555) 555-5555");
```

**Where str could be any of these formats:**
555-555-5555
(555)555-5555
(555) 555-5555
555 555 5555
5555555555
1 555 555 5555

Answer (score 8):

Try this
 I It's working.

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="mobile" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" title="Enter 10 digit mobile number" placeholder="Mobile number" required>
<button>
Save
</button>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/guljarpd/12b7v330/

Answer (score 3):

To validate Phone number using regular expression in java script.

In india phone is 10 digit and starting digits are 6,7,8 and 9.

Javascript and HTML code:

```js
function validate()
{
  var text = document.getElementById("pno").value;
  var regx = /^[6-9]\d{9}$/ ;
  if(regx.test(text))
    alert("valid");
  else
    alert("invalid");
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS compiler - knox97</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input id="pno" placeholder="phonenumber" type="tel" maxlength="10" > 
    </br></br>
    <button onclick="validate()" type="button">submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<title>Practice Session</title>
<body>           
<form name="RegForm" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post">  
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="Name"> </p><br>        
<p>Contact: <input type="text" name="Telephone"> </p><br>   
<p><input type="submit" value="send" name="Submit"></p>          
</form> 
</body>
<script> 
function validate()                                    
{ 
var name = document.forms["RegForm"]["Name"];                
var phone = document.forms["RegForm"]["Telephone"];  
if (name.value == "")                                  
{ 
window.alert("Please enter your name."); 
name.focus();
return false;
}
else if(isNaN(name.value) /*"%d[10]"*/)
{
alert("name confirmed");
}
else{ 
window.alert("please enter character"); 
}   
if (phone.value == "")                           
{ 
window.alert("Please enter your telephone number."); 
phone.focus();
return false; 
} 
else if(!isNaN(phone.value) /*phone.value == isNaN(phone.value)*/)
{
alert("number confirmed");
}
else{
window.alert("please enter numbers only");
}   
}
</script> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Having seen simply too many edge cases, I went for a simpler check:

```js
^(([0-9\ \+\_\-\,\.\^\*\?\$\^\#\(\)])|(ext|x)){1,20}$
```

The first thing one may point out is allowing repetition of "ext", but the purpose of this regex is to prevent users from accidentally entering email ids etc. instead of phone numbers, which it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Homepage-30-06-2016/Css.css" >
<title>Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function isChar(evt) {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) {

                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*Please Enter Your Name Only";
                document.getElementById("fullname").focus();
                document.getElementById("fullname").style.borderColor = 'red';
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("fullname").style.borderColor = '';

                return true;
            }
        }
</script>
</head>

<body>

        <h1 style="margin-left:20px;"Registration Form>Registration Form</h1><hr/>

           Name: <input id="fullname" type="text" placeholder="Full Name*"
                 name="fullname" onKeyPress="return isChar(event)" onChange="return isChar(event);"/><label id="error"></label><br /><br />

<button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onClick="return valid(event)" class="btn btn-link text-uppercase"> Submit now</button>
```

Comment: can you add details to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
        <input type='text' onChange={phonNumValidation(e)} 
         placeholder='Enter phone number...' id='phone_num' />
```

JAVASCRIPT

IT WILL ALLOW ONLY NUMBER,
it will not allow + sign and e,
and also string and regular expression

```
    phonNumValidation = (e)=>{
        e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g, "").replace(" ","")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
           .container__1{
               max-width: 450px;
               font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
           }
           .container__1 label{
               display: block;
               margin-bottom: 10px;
           }
           .container__1 label > span{
               float: left;
               width: 100px;
               color: #F072A9;
               font-weight: bold;
               font-size: 13px;
               text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
           }
           .container__1 fieldset{
               border-radius: 10px;
               -webkit-border-radious:10px;
               -moz-border-radoius: 10px;
               margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
               border: 1px solid #FFD2D2;
               padding: 20px;
               background:#FFF4F4 ;
               box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #FFE5E5;


           }
           .container__1 fieldset legend{
               color: #FFA0C9;
               border-top: 1px solid #FFD2D2 ;
               border-left: 1px solid #FFD2D2 ;
               border-right: 1px solid #FFD2D2 ;
               border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
               background: #FFF4F4;
               padding: 0px 8px 3px 8px;
               box-shadow: -0px -1px 2px #F1F1F1;
               font-weight: normal;
               font-size: 12px;
           }
           .container__1 textarea{
               width: 250px;
               height: 100px;
           }.container__1 input[type=text],
           .container__1 input[type=email],
           .container__1 select{
               border-radius: 3px;
               border: 1px solid #FFC2DC;
               outline: none;
               color: #F072A9;
               padding: 5px 8px 5px 8px;
               box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 4px #FFD5E7;
               background: #FFEFF6;
               

           }
           .container__1 input[type=submit],
           .container__1 input[type=button]{
               background: #EB3B88;
               border: 1px solid #C94A81;
               padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
               color: #FFCBE2;
               box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 3px #FF62A7;
               border-radius: 3px;
               font-weight: bold;
           }
           .required{
               color: red;
           }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container__1">
            <form name="RegisterForm" onsubmit="return(SubmitClick())">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Personal</legend>
                    <label for="field1"><span >Name<span class="required">*</span><input id="name" type="text" class="input-field" name="Name" value=""</label>
                    <label for="field2"><span >Email<span class="required">*</span><input placeholder="Ex: csa123@yahoo.in" id="email" type="email" class="input-field" name="Email" value=""</label>
                    <label for="field3"><span >Phone<span class="required">*</span><input placeholder="+919853004369" id="mobile" type="text" class="input-field" name="Mobile" value=""</label>
                    <label for="field4">
                        <span>Subject</span>
                        <select name="subject" id="subject" class="select-field">
                            <option value="none">Choose Your Sub..</option>
                            <option value="Appointment">Appiontment</option>
                            <option value="Interview">Interview</option>
                            <option value="Regarding a post">Regarding a post</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label><span></span><input type="submit"  ></label>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function SubmitClick(){
        _name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
        _email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
        _mobile = document.querySelector('#mobile').value;
        _subject = document.querySelector('#subject').value;
          if(_name == '' || _name == null ){
              alert('Enter Your Name');
              document.RegisterForm.Name.focus();
              return false; 
          } 
          var atPos = _email.indexOf('@');
         var dotPos = _email.lastIndexOf('.');

          if(_email == '' || atPos<1 || (dotPos - atPos)<2){
              alert('Provide Your Correct Email address');
              document.RegisterForm.Email.focus();
              return false;
          }
          var regExp = /^\+91[0-9]{10}$/;
          if(_mobile == '' || !regExp.test(_mobile)){
              alert('Please Provide your Mobile number as Ex:- +919853004369');
              document.RegisterForm.Mobile.focus();
              return false;
          }
          if(_subject == 'none'){
              alert('Please choose a subject');
              document.RegisterForm.subject.focus();
              return false;
          }else{
            alert (`success!!!:--'\n'Name:${_name},'\n' Mobile: ${_mobile},'\n' Email:${_email},'\n' Subject:${_subject},`)
          }
        
          
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "*Please Enter Your Name Only";
    document.getElementById("fullname").focus();
    document.getElementById("fullname").style.borderColor = 'red';
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("fullname").style.borderColor = '';
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please explain about how/why this code solves the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you