# I'm trying to form validate a phone number with a javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate a phone number. This doesn't seem to work though. Why doesn't this work?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var phone1 = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
        var phone2 = ^(\+0?1\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$;

        if ( phone1.value.match(phone2) ){
            return true;
        }else{
            alert("Please enter a valid phone number");
            return false;
        }   
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

    <label for="phone">Phone:</label><input name="phone" id="phone" value=""    placeholder="Zip..." type="text" onsubmit="return validateForm()"/>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

It definitely has something to do with the value comparison in the if statement, I just can't figure out how to accurately do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211225/validating-phone-numbers-using-javascript

Comment: Give it a shot in here: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern [**RegExp**](https://regex101.com/r/aR1wD5/2), base on your pattern validation phone number is following way you should validate.

View **[LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/w7917k87/1/)**

JS

```
function validateForm() {
    var re = /^(\+0?1\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$/; 
    var phone1 = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
    var m = re.exec(phone1);
    if (m && m[0]){
        return true; 
    }else{
        alert("Please enter a valid phone number");
        return false;
    }
 }
```

HTML

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input name="phone" id="phone" value="" placeholder="Zip..." type="text" onsubmit="return validateForm()" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

Use should use [RegExp](https://regex101.com/r/aR1wD5/3) Pattern

```
^((\+?)(1?(\-?)?))(\d{3})(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}$
```

[image]

Comment: I'm just curious, why do use `exec()` here? Is it more performant than `test()` or `match()`? Also, this regex will either match full string or not (because of `^$`), why use a `g` flag and a `while` loop?

Comment: Hello @sainaen yeah correct no need to use while loop because is this only single field, I update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var phone2 = ^(\+0?1\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$;
```

it's a wrong syntax for regexes in JavaScript, it should be

```
var phone2 = /^(\+0?1\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$/;
```

Also, you're getting field's value twice:

```
var phone1 = document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
//                                             ^
...
if (phone1.value.match(phone2)) {
//         ^ `value` property here is not defined
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rugb2p38/) with fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

Users tend to enter details in a textbox the way they like. It is an annoying experience if the form resticts them from entering the details in a specific fashion in a textbox. Its better to generalize your regex for such patterns.
@sainaen has pointed out the errors already but your regex can still fail in the following cases.

```
  +1-234-123-1234
  +1234-123-1234
  +1234123-1234
  +12341231234
  2341231234 
  434-123-1234   //with a space in the end or beginning
```