# Attach a function after clicking outside the input with javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

My html is:

```
<input class="UserInfo" type="text" placeholder="phone Format" id="Phone_num">
```

Here is my js:

```
function checkPhoneFormat(){
const phone = document.getElementById("Phone_num").value;
const phoneFormatRex = /^\+?[0-9(),.-]+$/;
var match = phoneFormatRex.exec(phone);
if (match) {
    document.getElementById("Phone_num").value = phone;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("Phone_num").value = "";
}
}
```

what i want is to check the format of the phone after the user click outside the input field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
    var input = document.getElementById("Phone_num");
    input.addEventListener("blur", function(){
        const phone = document.getElementById("Phone_num").value;
    const phoneFormatRex = /^\+?[0-9(),.-]+$/;
    var match = phoneFormatRex.exec(phone);
    if (match) {
        document.getElementById("Phone_num").value = phone;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("Phone_num").value = "";
    }
    })
```

```html
<input class="UserInfo" type="text" placeholder="phone Format" id="Phone_num">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("Phone_num").value
```

AND

```
document.getElementById("phone_num").value
```

There is a typo, Attribute values are always case-sensitive.
The id value should either be `Phone_num` or `phone_num`

Comment: I corrected that typo and still doesnt check the format of the input after clicking outside the field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211225/validating-phone-numbers-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
<input type="text" onfocusout="myFunction()">
```

You can read more about it here [W3 Schools onFocusOut](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp)

Comment: I guess this would just focus on the input field not check its type

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should clarify. Using `onfocusout`  with your function would cause it to run the `checkPhoneFormat()` function when focus is lost (e.g. when the user clicks off the input or tabs to the next input.) `onfocusout` does not make the input be in focus.

Comment: yeah I've tried and it does not check the format of the value inside the input. So what can I do to make it check the format of the value of the input

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php